# Solution for 'function or expression too complex' in string.char

Tags: lua

I have a problem when using `string.char`. After I searching on any web, this is because limitation of stack frame.

My code is like below :

```
function tochar(str)
    if type(str) ~= 'string' then
        return nil
    end
    local Result = {}
    for i = 1,#str do
        table.insert(Result, string.byte(string.sub(str,i, i)))
    end
    return table.concat(Result,',')
end

Content = 'hello world'
local result = tochar(Content)
local data = 'local code = load(string.dump(load(string.char('..result..'))))()\n'
```

It will be fine if my Content not too long. But if I try to use too long Content, error says `functíon or expression too complex`.

There is any solutions? Or maybe, another code but with the same purpose as I need?

Thanks.

Comment: Any Lua function (including `string.char`) can't have too many arguments.

Comment: Lua VM has only 255 registers, hence the limit.

Comment: Ok, looks like I need to find another way.

Comment: Though this is unrelated to your question, you can simplify `tochar` to `function tochar(str) if type(str) == 'string' then return table.concat({ string.byte(str, 1, -1) }, ',') end end`.

Comment: Well, nice. it is pretty simple than as I write. How to bring back tostr? I try using gsub, but not yet works perfectly.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff "*Lua VM has only 255 registers, hence the limit.*" As far as I remember, that's only a default though, and can be changed while compiling Lua, so it can be even less on some more confined environment (think Lua on embedded devices)

Comment: @MahaDewanto please edit your question and explain what exactly do you want to achieve with the code you posted. As a side note, LuaJIT has a much higher limit on the number of function arguments (something like 2^16 - 1), IIRC.

Comment: @viluon - Isn't the point of OP's program clear enough?  It's widespread used very simple obfuscation popular among Lua beginners.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I was not aware. If it is so, OP should still edit the question to reflect this fact, to make the question easier to find and attract answers.